# Why isn't copy_to_user printing the correct results?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have a linked list of mailboxes and I'm trying to copy their ids to the userspace variable `mbxList` but it is not printing out correctly.

```
asmlinkage long sys_listMailboxes(unsigned long * mbxList,
                    unsigned long K)
{
  int counter = 0;
  MBOX * currentBox;
  unsigned long * toUser;

  list_for_each_entry(currentBox, &mailbox_list, list)
    {
      if(counter != K)
    {
      printk("The id is: %lu\n", currentBox->id);
      toUser = &currentBox->id;
      copy_to_user(mbxList, toUser, sizeof toUser);
      mbxList++;
      counter++;
    }
    }
  return counter;
}
```

When I check prints in the kernel using `dmesg` I see the correct output:
`The id is: 1111`
but in the user space when I try to print it out I get the output:
`The id is: 1474660693` which is incorrect.

The C code snippet implementing this system call is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syscall.h>

long listMbox(unsigned long * mbxList, unsigned long K)
{
  return syscall(__NR_listMailboxes, mbxList, K);
}

int main(void)
{
   unsigned long * mbxlist;
   unsigned long K = 2;

   listMailboxes(mbxlist, K);       

   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < K; i++)
   {
      printf("Mailbox id is: %lu\n", *mbxList);
      mbxList++;
   }
}
```

I get the same `1474660693` number everytime so I don't think it is a memory address. I thought I was giving the size argument in `copy_to_user` too big but that doesnt seem to be the case since. I have no idea what is wrong, I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your user code never calls that `listMbox` function. Please make a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `sizeof toUser` in the kernel part, but actually copying data that is **pointed to** by `toUser`.

So that is wrong. You are copying from an int the size of a pointer bytes.

I suggest using `sizeof *toUser` although you might need parenthesis like `sizeof(*toUser)`

Comment: Parenthesis not needed though.

Comment: I changed it to `sizeof *toUser` and I still get the same number `1474660693` in the user space. Am I putting in the correct type of arguments? I want to copy the id to the user variable `mbxList`

Comment: Turns out I just needed to allocated memory to the `mbxList` in the driver.....Thanks for your help though anyway

Comment: Just so you know, if you're implementing syscalls in your driver, you're doing something very wrong. Syscalls aren't added to the kernel without good reason and only when the other kernel interfaces aren't appropriate.